# How can I make this MySQL Query with three tables work?

Tags: mysql

I have the following Database scheme:

---

**Content:**

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id |  name  | user_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | name11 |      23 |
|  2 | name22 |      34 |
|  3 | name33 |      45 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

The User column contains the User ID

---

**Tags:**

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | content_id | tag_id |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |      1 |
|  2 |          1 |      4 |
|  3 |          1 |      5 |
|  4 |          2 |      3 |
|  5 |          2 |      4 |
|  6 |          2 |      5 |
|  7 |          2 |      7 |
|  8 |          3 |      2 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Every Content has got multiple Tags

---

**Users:**

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| id |  name   |     rank     |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 23 | James   | beginner     |
| 34 | Arthur  | professional |
| 45 | Gosling | newbie       |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

---

What I'm trying to do is to get all contents with a specific tag and the user-name + rank of the content creator.

So for example if I'm requesting Tag 5 (Content 1 and 2 contain Tag 5) the Query should return:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| content_id | content_name | creator_id | creator_name | creator_rank |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|          1 | name11       |         23 | James        | beginner     |
|          2 | name22       |         34 | Arthur       | professional |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I tried was

```
SELECT content.id, content.name, content.user_id, users.name, users.rank
FROM tags 
JOIN content, users 
WHERE tags.tag_id = 5 AND users.id = content.user_id
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: [**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/927fb8/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use proper joins:

```
SELECT t.content_id, c.name content_name, c.user_id creator_id, u.name creator_name, u.rank creator_rank
FROM tags t
JOIN content c ON c.id = t.content_id  
JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE t.tag_id = 5
```

The "modern" join syntax has been around now for more than 20 years.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly! I can accept it in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT C.id as content_id, C.name as content_name, C.user_id as creator_id, U.name as creator_name, U.rank as creator_rank
FROM tags T INNER JOIN content C
    ON T.content_id = C.id
INNER JOIN users U
    ON C.user_id = U.id
WHERE T.tag_id = 5
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    content.id,
    content.name,
    content.user_id,
    users.name,
    users.rank
FROM
    tags
JOIN content
JOIN users 
ON tags.tag_id = 5
AND users.id = content.user_id
AND content.id = tags.content_id;
```

You forgot content.id=tags.content_id.
Also you should use the `ON` operator for joins instead of `WHERE`.